Cygwin shell behavior when running native executable
Since Windows is not a fully compliant POSIX system, there are significant challenges in implementing an efficient emulation of fork on Cygwin.
Cygwin still does a decent job of it but the performance of it is not such that we can expect the maximum performance from such programs compared with one backed by pure WinAPI.
Despite this, I would still like to use some utilities provided by Cygwin.
Now here is my issue - I am not sure if Cygwin will always implement new processes using fork or not.
Leaving aside altering the behavior via code, the more nuanced matter I'm concerned about here is whether Cygwin is capable of determining to a reasonable degree of significance when to use its fork emulation and when a process is better off being handled WinAPI way without impacting the Unix experience.
I was planning on switching to the mintty as my default command prompt. Since mintty itself is running backed by the Cygwin dll, I wonder how it handles regular native cli programs. I do not want a case where even if I am running a '.exe' that is not a part of Cygwin, the launched process's behavior meets at least one of the following:

If I have started it as a new process, it was started via Cygwin's fork emulation.
Its delegation & control is taken over by Cygwin emulation and all other processes/threads emanating from the program is also being accomplished by the fork-emulation.

If any of the above cases indeed turn out to be true, processes started via the mintty and thus the Cygwin shell would possibly prevent even the native  processes from performing efficiently.
Due to being unable to articulate these concerns in a coincise manner, I am unable to find information regarding this either.
I would like to know if Cygwin shell simply delegates native processes to the OS or runs everything via the Cygwin environment.
Apart from the challenges of fork, a classic complaint of Cygwin appears to be that it 'runs' slow. I've never noticed this myself, and would assume something like its 'tree' command to run a little slow sometimes - but it would not be desirable if a windows command like simple 'find' or 'dir' was also taking longer on mintty.
